# solr - synonyms.txt vs managed sy

Tags: solr

I realize there are two ways to add synonyms: 
1. using synonyms.txt and SynonymFilterFactory
2. using rest api by using ManagedSynonymFilterFactory.

The question is - can both of these be used together? If so, if a new entry is added to synonyms.txt, will it be returned when fetching synonyms using rest api and vice versa?

We currently use synonyms.txt but want to use the rest apis to update synonyms on the fly without having to restart solr. At the same time, we want to retain synonyms added using synonyms.txt and also retain ability to add new words using the txt file.

Also, if we add synonyms using the txt file, should solr always require a restart before changes are reflected? Or just a core reload is supposed to do it? - if the latter, it for some reason doesnt' work for us.